# Symfony2/Doctrine2 double join

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, inner-join

I have the following situation: a table named HRMgmt contains events happening to a user, caused by another user, so in my entity class I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 */
protected $changed_by;
```

I want to do a double join to get both id, name and surname of the user this event is related to and id, name and surname of the user who caused the HRMgmt event (called changed_by)

My query is built like follows:

```
$events = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
        'SELECT u1.id currentuserid, u1.name currentusername, u1.surname currentusersurname, u2.id changedbyuserid, u2.name changedbyusername, u2.surname changedbyusersurname, h.is_active, h.timestamp, h.started_at, h.finished_at, r.name rolename FROM AppBundle:HRMgmtEvent h, AppBundle:Role r
         INNER JOIN h.user u1
         INNER JOIN h.changed_by u2
         WHERE h.project = :projectid
         AND h.role = r.id
         ORDER BY h.timestamp DESC, h.is_active DESC' 
        )
        ->setParameter('projectid', $project->getId())
        ->getResult();
```

But throws the following error
    Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'h2_.user_id' in 'on clause'

Is the join properly performed? What am I missing here?

The question is similar to the following: [JOIN DQL (symfony2) multiple joins between two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484945/join-dql-symfony2-multiple-joins-between-two-tables)

Actually my case is even simpler as I cannot have null values...

My DB is in sync with my entities having run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

EDIT:

here is the schema of HRMgmt:

```
CREATE TABLE `hrmgmt` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`project_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`changed_by_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`started_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`finished_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
`role_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `IDX_B3C74883A76ED395` (`user_id`),
KEY `IDX_B3C74883828AD0A0` (`changed_by_id`),
KEY `IDX_B3C74883166D1F9C` (`project_id`),
KEY `IDX_B3C74883D60322AC` (`role_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_B3C74883166D1F9C` FOREIGN KEY (`project_id`) REFERENCES `projects` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_B3C74883828AD0A0` FOREIGN KEY (`changed_by_id`) REFERENCES `fos_user` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_B3C74883A76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `fos_user` (`id`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_B3C74883D60322AC` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1042 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Here is the User:

```
CREATE TABLE `fos_user` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
...several other fields...
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`surname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_957A647992FC23A8` (`username_canonical`),
UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_957A6479A0D96FBF` (`email_canonical`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us you DB schema for `AppBundle:HRMgmtEvent` and `AppBundle:User` entities?

Answer (score 0):

Both properties are mapped to the same field on the DB, `user_id`, which is the default mapping of Doctrine on ManyToOne associations (model_id). To solve that you should pick different column names for each property, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id")
 */
protected $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="changed_by_id")
 */
protected $changed_by;
```

After that you should be able to do your join.

Comment: Sounded promising but...same error :( . I also tried changing the query by substituting h.user with h.user_id (and same for the other) but it tells me that "HRMgmtEvent has no association named user_id" (which was expected, but, you know...)

Comment: what error returned? exactly the same? did you try set the ON manually for the joins?

Comment: I solved it, the problem was that I had also to make a proper join with the role table: "INNER JOIN h.role r" instead of the clause "AND h.role = r.id"